# Fluent Validation Failing with Excessive Executions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, fluentvalidation

So I'm using Fluent Validation in an MVC site.  On submission of a form there are attendees to an event and they are run through some validation.

One of the properties on the attendee view model contains a collection of questions and answers.  In the instance I'm looking at there are 2 attendees, one has 4 questions the other has 2.  However, one of the attendees is a child.  The questions only need to be answered by the adult attendee.

The validator in question looks like this:

```
public class EventQuestionAnswerViewModelValidator : AbstractValidator<EventQuestionAnswerViewModel>
{
    private AttendeeViewModel _model;
    public EventQuestionAnswerViewModelValidator(AttendeeViewModel model)
    {
        _model = model;
        if (!_model.IsChild)
        {
            Trace.TraceInformation($"trace Performing Event Question Validation on {_model.FirstName}. IsChild: {_model.IsChild}");
            ...
        {
        else
        {
            Trace.TraceInformation($"NOT Performing Event Question Validation on {_model.FirstName}. IsChild: {_model.IsChild}");
        }
```

Baring in mind there are a total of 6 instances of this in the posted data, I get 189 trace entries in the event viewer.  4 of which contain the adult attendees first name.  This makes sense due to their being 4 questions on that attendee.  IsChild is correctly set on the view model that contains the child and I have 2 entries for this model accurately showing that it wasn't validated.

The other 183 trace entries look like this:

> Performing Event Question Validation on . IsChild: False

Why would this validator be executed such a vast number of times?  Where are all these `null` object instances coming from?  Maybe its the same instance, I don't know.

I've used FV extensively in many projects, including MVC sites and I've never seen this behaviour before.

Comment: Why don't put a break-point into constructor and find out when the validator is being executed? It seems like empty `AttendeeViewModel` instances were passed to your validator. BTW, why do you have a parameter in the constructor at all? It seems like you're misusing the [library](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/wiki/b.-Creating-a-Validator).

Comment: I've done all those things already.  Also constructor parameters are supported like this: RuleFor(x => x.EventQuestionAnswers).SetCollectionValidator(model => new EventQuestionAnswerViewModelValidator(model));

Comment: Have you tried to rewrite it like this: `RuleFor(x => x.EventQuestionAnswers).SetCollectionValidator(new EventQuestionAnswerViewModelValidator()).When(x => !x.IsChild); `

Comment: That's actually how it's set now `When(x => !x.IsChild, () =>`